# List View ERROR

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, swipe, android-fragmentactivity

i create this program to have a listView inside a SwipeView, but the went i test the apk always stop,
I try to put breakpoints but i can´t find the problem,
this is the JAVA:

```
    package com.sapires.Joes;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.sapires.Pizza.R;

public class Ementa extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    private Context context;
    Context cont;
    String[] Mtitles;
    String[] Mdescriptions;
    int[] images = { R.drawable.um, R.drawable.dois, R.drawable.tres,
            R.drawable.quatro,R.drawable.cinco,R.drawable.seis };

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ementa_2, container, false);

        Resources res = getResources();
        Mtitles = res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        Mdescriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);

        list = (ListView) android.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        VivzAdapter adapter = new VivzAdapter(context, Mtitles, images, Mdescriptions);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        return android;
    }

}
class VivzAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descriptionArray;

    VivzAdapter(Context c,String[] titles, int imgs[], String[] desc) {
        super(c, R.layout.auxementa_2, R.id.textView3, titles);
        this.context = c;
        this.images = imgs;
        this.titleArray = titles;
        this.descriptionArray = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auxementa_2, parent, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
        myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
    08-05 23:49:13.474: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(16938): Parent view is not a TextView
08-05 23:49:13.484: D/skia(16938): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 273 
08-05 23:49:13.484: I/PersonaManager(16938): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
08-05 23:49:13.644: D/AndroidRuntime(16938): Shutting down VM
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938): Process: com.sapires.Pizza, PID: 16938
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938): android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment Ementa{68594c68 #1 id=0x7f070014 android:switcher:2131165204:1} did not call through to super.onAttach()
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:412)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5364)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2548)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17478)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2262)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1391)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1590)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6585)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-05 23:49:13.654: E/AndroidRuntime(16938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
```

THis is the overall of the eclipse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVgAe.jpg

Comment: `android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment Ementa{68594c68 #1 id=0x7f070014 android:switcher:2131165204:1} did not call through to super.onAttach()`. Read up on stacktraces [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;
}
```

Comment: Thks a lot, you save my day

Comment: You just need read the exception: android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment Ementa{68594c68 #1 id=0x7f070014 android:switcher:2131165204:1} did not call through to super.onAttach()